# How do I keep my starter seed project up to date with the main repo?

Tags: angular, github

If I were to use the below seed project as a basis for an Angular 2 app, how would I keep my own version of the app updated with the latest bug fixes and improvements from the seed project?

Is such a thing even possible?

Here is the seed project I plan to use: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with

```
git pull origin master
```

if you cloned the repository with `git clone https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed`.

---

Otherwise you need to add that repository as a remote to your existing one:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed
```

Then you can pull changes with:

```
git pull upstream master
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What if I changed the origin to my own remote master branch? Would I always have to keep two remote url references (one to mine and one to the seed project?)

Comment: Yes, exactly - just keep another remote in your git config from which you pull the updates.

Comment: Thanks much for yor help!